# Django detect changes to multiple fields in same model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm using some javascript libraries that won't let me pass in `self.full_name` created using `def full_name(self):`

Wondering how I should go about updating a full_name field based on changes to (or creation of) any of the 3 name fields.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  first_name = StringProperty(max_length=25)
  middle_name = StringProperty(max_length=25)
  last_name = StringProperty(max_length=50)

  full_name = StringProperty(max_length=100)
  # lots of Icelanders have the same first and last name...
  full_name_includes_middle_name = BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Right now I'm looking into @receiver and `created or update_fields` is looking promising...

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def update_full_name(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
  if instance.middle_name_is_part_of_full_name == True:
    if created or update_fields is 'first_name' or 'middle_name' or 'last_name':
      instance.full_name = instance.first_name + " " + instance.middle_name + " " + instance.last_name
      instance.save()
  else:
    if created or update_fields is 'first_name' or 'last_name':
      self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
      instance.save()
```

^ but this gives the error:

```
update_full_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_fields'
```

Comment: yeah signal listener `@receiver` with `update_fields` will work.

Comment: @YusefBH updated my question with some receiver code. trying to figure out how to pass those fields in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is no diff between create or update operation.

You can try this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Employee)
def update_full_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if instance.middle_name_is_part_of_full_name == True:
      instance.full_name = f"{instance.first_name} {instance.middle_name} {instance.last_name}"
  else:
      instance.full_name = f"{instance.first_name} {instance.last_name}"
```

Comment: thanks so much =) im trying it out now. 
`hooked() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'`

Comment: looks like this error is happening right after `form.is_valid: form.save` i'll fix it

Comment: Yes. `line 206, in save
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: hooked() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'`

Comment: This is weird, ok try without `update_fields`, I updated the answer.

Comment: new error. maybe it has to do with calling save from post_save?
`encoding with 'idna' codec failed (RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481625/how-can-i-prevent-post-save-recursion-in-django

Comment: good post, yep you're right. we're calling save from post_save. so try `post_save.disconnect(update_full_name, sender=sender)`. Check out the answer, i guess this time it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Also f"" where f goes outside the quotes
```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def update_full_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if instance.middle_name_is_part_of_full_name == True:
      instance.full_name = f"{instance.first_name} {instance.middle_name} {instance.last_name}"
  else:
      instance.full_name = f"{instance.first_name} {instance.last_name}"
```