# how to populate a model field via django signals with post_save?

Tags: django

After creating a model object I would like to use a `post_save` signal to populate another model field in the same object with the ID and other values.

But the real question here is, how do i access the field from the instance? nothing worked

**Example:**
User creates an object -> `id` of the object is 93 -> I would like to add `#00093` as value of another field in the same object.

**models.py**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ticket)
def ticket_designation(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.designation = "#" + "000" + str(instance.id)
    print("Ticket" + instance.designation + " was created.")
```

Comment: you want `designation` to be created once or everytime the `post_save` signals runs?

Comment: once when the object is created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you really want to do this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ticket)
def ticket_designation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        designation = "#" + "000" + str(instance.id)
        Ticket.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(designation=designation)
        print("Ticket" + instance.designation + " was created.")
```

*Explanation:*

why use `if created`: designation is only created once when the new Ticket is created. It's not updated every time you save the same object.

why use `Ticket.objects.filter(..).update(..)` : we cannot do `instance.save()` as it'll then call this `post_save` again and recursion occurs. `.update` on queryset does not call signals so we're safe.

---

If you want to use `instance.save` you might want to look at [how to prevent post_save recursion in django.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481625/how-can-i-prevent-post-save-recursion-in-django/39483052)

Comment: nice it worked, i had to tune it fully for my customization purposes, but i got the hang out of it thanks to your filter + update recommendation, thanks very much have a nice day!